# Unexpected 'sortBy' Behavior with Ramda

Tags: javascript, sorting, functional-programming, ramda.js

Application of 'sortBy' producing unexpected results.

I've gotta be doing something stoopid. This is such a basic operation.

```
const input = [4,3,2,1];

const sort = list => R.sortBy(R.ascend(R.identity))(list);

console.log(sort(input)); // [ 4, 3, 2, 1 ]
```

I would expect the output of the 'console.log' invocation to be [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ], but it is not: the output is [ 4, 3, 2, 1 ], same as the input. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The types don't match. From the documentation, the [`sortBy`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#sortBy) function requires a sorting function of the type `Ord b => a -> b`. However, the [`R.ascend(R.identity)`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#ascend) function has the type `a -> a -> Number`. Just use `R.sortBy(R.identity)` instead.

Comment: Excellent. Got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by Aadit M Shah in the comments you're not using `sortBy` correctly.

Here's quick overview of how to sort in Ramda:

## sort

> Returns a copy of the list, sorted according to the comparator function, which should accept two values at a time and return a negative number if the first value is smaller, a positive number if it's larger, and zero if they are equal.

One case use [`subtract`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#subtract) to sort in ascending order:

```
sort(subtract, [4, 1, 2, 3]);
//=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Or to sort in descending, just [`flip`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#flip) it:

```
sort(flip(subtract), [4, 1, 2, 3]);
//=> [4, 3, 2, 1]
```

`sort` simply expects a function that can accept two parameters which can be compared with `<` or `>`.

So how would you sort an array of strings? Strings can be compared with `<` or `>` but using `subtract` wouldn't make sense. This is where [`ascend`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#ascend) (or [`descend`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#descend)) can be useful:

> Makes an ascending comparator function out of a function that returns a value that can be compared with < and >.

```
sort(ascend(identity), ["b", "a", "B", "A"]);
//=> ["A", "B", "a", "b"]
```

And if you want to make a case insensitive comparison:

```
sort(ascend(toLower), ["b", "a", "B", "A"]);
//=> ["a", "A", "b", "B"]
```

## sortBy

As we saw, `sort` expects that you supply it with a function that accepts two parameters that can be compared together using `<` or `>`. Numbers and strings can be compared with these operators so if you can give them to Ramda directly then:

```
sortBy(identity, [4, 1, 2, 3]);
//=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

is the same as:

```
sort(subtract, [4, 1, 2, 3]);
//=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

However as far as I can tell, `sortBy` will always sort things in ascending order.

## sortWith

You use `sortWith` when you can have multiple sort criteria:

- Sort by age in ascending order
- Sort by name in descending order

```
sortWith([ascend(prop('age')), descend(prop('name'))], [
  {age: 40, name: 'John'},
  {age: 40, name: 'Zack'},
  {age: 10, name: 'Liam'},
  {age: 20, name: 'Bill'}
]);
//=> [
//=>   {age: 10, name: "Liam"},
//=>   {age: 20, name: "Bill"},
//=>   {age: 40, name: "Zack"},
//=>   {age: 40, name: "John"}
//=> ]
```

Comment: Nice!  A better example of `sortBy` might be `sortBy(prop('age'))`.  A gloss on these: `sort` takes a comparator, just like `Array.prototype.sort`.  `sortWith` takes an array of comparators, returning the first non-zero value, and `sortBy` *creates*  a comparator out a function that returns a type that can be compared with `<` and uses that comparator. ... You're right that `sortBy` doesn't have *descending* version. Perhaps that's a gap Ramda should fill.

Comment: Thanks @ScottSauyet that's good feedback. I'll edit my answer.