# How to compose an ascending/descending sort in Ramda

Tags: javascript, sorting, ramda.js

I have a React component with a sorting headers table. This code works as planned:

```
  //definitions and imports...
  const [sort, setSort] = useState({column: 'rank', direction: 'ascending', isNumber: true});

  const handleSort = (column, isNumber = false) => () => {
    let direction = (sort.column !== column) ? 'ascending' : (sort.direction === 'ascending' ? 'descending' : 'ascending');
    setSort({column, direction, isNumber});
  };

  const getSortedData = (data) => {
    let sorted = R.sortBy(
      R.compose(
        sort.isNumber ? Number.parseFloat : R.toLower,
        R.prop(sort.column)
      ),
      data
    );
    return sort.direction === 'ascending' ? sorted : sorted.reverse();
  }
 //rest of the component...
```

However, I'm sure there's a way to use `R.compose` to conditionally `ascend` or `descend` the sort (based on the `sort.direction` property), and thus allow me to remove the last line of `getSortedData` and the `reverse` array op.

I tried several things (like composing `ascend` with `prop`, using the conditional in the compose etc.), but it all breaks down the code.

While it works well now, can anyone help me make it more `Ramda`ish?

**Update - adding the solution here for posterity's sake:**

```
const getSortedData = (data) => {
  return R.sort(
    (sort.direction === 'ascending' ? R.ascend : R.descend)(
      R.compose(
        sort.isNumber ? Number.parseFloat : R.toLower,
        R.prop(sort.column)
      )
    )
  )(data);
}
```

Things I've learned:

1. `R.sort` returns a function, and not an array, so you need to send `data` in as a parameter to the whole function.
2. `R.ascend`/`R.descend` also expect the function as a paremeter, and therefore should not be a parameter of `R.compose` on their own.

Comment: Both of your learnings are a little off.  (1) `sort` returns the sorted array, but like all Ramda functions is curried, so if you don't supply the array on the first call, you get back a new function waiting for it.  In fact, in this example, you would be very slightly better off replacing `)(data)` with `, data)`. (2) `ascend` and `descend` are fine in a `compose`, but the value passed to them must be a function that returns an element of some ordered type (one which can reasonably be compared via `<`.) This could just as easily be written with a nested `compose` function.

Comment: Also note that writing `getSortedData` as you have means that you will have to build up the main function every time you use it.  There's not much going on there, so it's not likely a big deal, but if you pulled it out into a separate function, it might be reusable.

Comment: @ScottSauyet I actually came here to see how it can all be composed using `compose` - if you have a suggestion, I'd be glad to hear.

I tried passing `data` as a parameter to sort, and ot some sort of an error - I'll look into it again.

Finally, I understand what you're saying regarding rebuilding the function - I'll refactor it such that it can be reused.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I would do something like this, wrapping `ascend` or `descend` around the composition:

```js
const makeSorter = (sortConfig) => R.sort (
  (sortConfig.direction === 'descending' ? R.descend : R.ascend) ( R.compose (
    sortConfig.isNumber ? Number.parseFloat : R.toLower,
    R.prop (sortConfig.column)
  ))
)

const people = [
  {name: 'fred', age: 25},
  {name: 'barney', age: 28},
  {name: 'wilma', age: 29},
  {name: 'betty', age: 22}
]

const byName = {direction: 'descending', column: 'name', isNumber: false}

const getSortedData = makeSorter(byName)

console .log (
  getSortedData (people)
)

const byAge = {direction: 'ascending', column: 'age', isNumber: true}

console .log (
  makeSorter (byAge) (people)
)
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```

I would personally prefer to write it with destructuring, as such:

```js
const makeSorter = ({direction, isNumber, column}) => R.sort (
  (direction === 'descending' ? R.descend : R.ascend) ( R.compose (
    isNumber ? Number.parseFloat : R.toLower,
    R.prop (column)
  ))
)
```

but that doesn't change anything fundamental.

Comment: Yes! That's exactly what I was looking for! I used your answer to compose the final version - I'll post it in the question for posterity's sake. Cheers mate!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ascend`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#ascend) or [`descend`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#descend) with `converge`:

1. The first branch works out whether that's an ascending or descending sort
2. The second branch works out which field (and which transformation) the sort should operate on

```js
const arr = [{a: 10, b: 'ZZZ'}, {a: 5, b: 'ccc'}, {a: 11, b: 'aaa'}];

const makeSort = converge(call, [
  ({dir}) => dir === 'ascending' ? ascend : descend,
  ({isNumber, key}) => isNumber ? compose(parseFloat, prop(key)) : compose(toLower, prop(key))]);

const ascSortB = makeSort({dir: 'ascending', isNumber: false, key: 'b'});
const descSortA = makeSort({dir: 'descending', isNumber: true, key: 'a'});

console.log(sort(ascSortB, arr));
console.log(sort(descSortA, arr));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script>const {sort, ascend, descend, prop, converge, call, compose, toLower} = R;</script>
```

*You may also find [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56105016/1244884) useful*

Comment: I know I can use it like that - I'm trying to compose it into the existing function.

Comment: You are manually reverting the sort, whereas if you use either `ascend` or `descend` with `sort` (as opposed to `sortBy`) you wouldn't need to do that.

Comment: But I take your point about trying to compose the different criteria of your sort. Will post an update.

Comment: There is some real confusion around `sort`, `sortBy`, and `sortWith` that I don't really know how to resolve in Ramda docs.